# Hide Settings Icon in iOS hybrid remote app

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I have followed the directions in [Hiding the Settings Icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_hide_gear_icon.htm) for my hybrid remote app by modifying the AppDelegate.m class generated by Cordova as follows (added lines prefixed with a plus):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
+ #import "SFLoginViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
  self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
  + SFLoginViewController *loginViewController = [SFLoginViewController sharedInstance];    
  + loginViewController.showNavbar = NO;
  + loginViewController.showSettingsIcon = NO;

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

I removed the app from the simulator but the navbar and gear icon are still present. What else needs to be done to remove the gear icon from login page?

Comment: Maybe this question belongs to stackoverflow?

Comment: Why migrate? This is specifically about SF and an SDK they provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I modified the wrong AppDelegate file. I had to modify AppDelegate+SalesforceHybridSDK.m instead of AppDelegate.m. Once SFLoginViewController.h was imported and the "loginViewController" lines were added the status bar and settings icon were hidden as desired.